# DLL para usar NewtonSoft en aplicacion Centura

Tags: c#, .net, dll, newtonsoft

les comento, necesito hacer una dll en c#, para ser utilizado por otro programa que usa Centura... si no lo han oido, es un lenguaje muy viejo, algo similar al turbo pascal ja... la cuestion, es que es mi primera vez con un dll, necesito que dentro, llame a Newtonsoft, ya que lo que se hara, es generar un json con los datos que manden desde centura, lo guardara en un txt y de alli, lo leeran. Lo que me pasa, es que cuando, dentro de la misma solucion la pruebo, funciona muy bien. Ahora, cuando genero la dll, la saco de la carpeta bin, y la llevo, junto al .pdb, para probar desde otro programa de c#, externo a la solucion, me arroja el siguiente error al llamar a la funcion de la DLL:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo

especificado.'

Lo que veo, que ademas de hacerme el .dll y el .pdb, me hace un json, que dice lo siguiente:

```
     {
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0": {
      "PruebaQrGeneratorV2NetCore/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "QrgenV2DllNetCore": "1.0.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "PruebaQrGeneratorV2NetCore.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "12.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "12.0.3.23909"
          }
        }
      },
      "QrgenV2DllNetCore/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Newtonsoft.Json": "12.0.3"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "QrgenV2DllNetCore.dll": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "PruebaQrGeneratorV2NetCore/1.0.0": {
      "type": "project",
      "serviceable": false,
      "sha512": ""
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-6mgjfnRB4jKMlzHSl+VD+oUc1IebOZabkbyWj2RiTgWwYPPuaK1H97G1sHqGwPlS5npiF5Q0OrxN1wni2n5QWg==",
      "path": "newtonsoft.json/12.0.3",
      "hashPath": "newtonsoft.json.12.0.3.nupkg.sha512"
    },
    "QrgenV2DllNetCore/1.0.0": {
      "type": "project",
      "serviceable": false,
      "sha512": ""
    }
  }
}
```

es como que faltaria o la ruta o el dll de newtonsoft, pero no se como hacerlo, no se si me falta algun paso para poder compilar todo junto en 1 sola Dll, o si debo modificar ese Json, probe esto ultimo, pero no funciono tampoco. Espero no haya sido demasiado larga la pregunta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Copiar el archivo dll por si solo no es suficiente, prueba copiar todo el contenido de la carpeta bin. En cuanto a la integración con Centura, si es tan viejo como mencionas tal vez no soporte el dll .NET directamente, de ser así, investiga si Centura soporta objetos COM

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez Mil gracias!!! ahora si pude. No me habia dado cuenta de eso. Era muy obvio y no lo vi. Muchas gracias!